# JavaScript theme switcher issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a theme switcher , but currently it not switching between the style sheets.

I have the following code below  and I want to switch between the stylesheet to apply the red or grey themes and grey is the default theme.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" title="red" href="css/red.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" title="blue" href="css/grey.css" type="text/css">

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#red').click(function (){
   $('link[href="css/red.css"]').attr('href','css/red.css');
   alert("red");
});
$('#grayscale').click(function (){
   $('link[href="css/grey.css"]').attr('href','css/grey.css');
   alert("grey");
});

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<p> lorem ipsum lorem iuipsum </p>



<button id="original">Original</button><br />
<button id="grayscale">Grayscale</button>


 <a href="#"  id="red"> red</a>
 <a href="#"  id="grayscale"> grey</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't actually modify anything:

```
$('link[href="css/red.css"]').attr('href','css/red.css');
```

It finds the `link` which links to `red.css` and... sets it to link to `red.css`.  So, no change.  It sounds like you *meant* to find the *grey* one and link it to red:

```
$('link[href="css/grey.css"]').attr('href','css/red.css');
```

And the same thing for the other line, of course:

```
$('link[href="css/red.css"]').attr('href','css/grey.css');
```

Additionally, you probably only want *one* `link` tag on the page.  Having both means that both styles are always applied.  So "switching" between them wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I updated my code, it switches to red from original grey. But it doesnt seem to switch back when i click on grey again.

Comment: @user244394 You shouldn't edit your question to remove the original problem. This answer solves the original problem. Your new problem stems from the fact that the stylesheet has been cached by the browser so it doesn't bother reloading it. Adding a timestamp to the urls (`'css/grey.css?_=' + Date.now()`) should fix that.

Comment: @MikeC: Would caching really cause that behavior, though?  You're right that a timestamp is a great way to disable caching of otherwise idempotent resources.  But in this case they are two different URLs for the two different stylesheets already.  I wonder if something else may be going wrong in the OP's setup that we might not be seeing in the posted example.

Comment: @user244394: Note also that your HTML is invalid because you're re-using `id` values.  So this: `$('#grayscale')` currently has undefined behavior.

Comment: @David It does. That's how it ensures that the same stylesheet isn't accidentally loaded multiple times.